# Finding $x$ in the domain of the function where the tangent line is horizontal

Tags: calculus

$$ y = x^3 - 4x^2 +4x + 2$$

I have to find all the values of the domain of the function where the tangent line at the point (x,f(x)) is horizontal.

I wasn't so sure on how to start this problem, so the first thing I did was derive the function:
$$y' = 3x^2-8x + 4$$

If this isn't right, can someone correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's absolutely the way to start. Now, the tangent line being horizontal means that the slope--which is $y'$--should be...what? That gives you the equation that you need to solve.

Comment: I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: So the horizontal line is zero. After that, I use the FOIL to solve for the points?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "use the FOIL." But yes, you need to set $3x^2-8x+4=0$ and solve by whatever method you can.